# Subscribe newsletter message when unsubscribing

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

Whenever a  user unsubscribes from the newsletter from the site, theres a succes message displayed for subscribing. I simply call the messages like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You don't want to display the message? Or you want to edit it?

Comment: @SanderMangel I want to edit it. When I `unsubscribe` from the newsletter a message is displayed with `thank you for subscribing`

Answer (score 1):

The message shown comes from a translation file. You can find the file under `app/locale/[your language]/Mage_Newsletter.csv`, find the string you want to change and edit the second column in the CSV to whatever you want the message to be

Comment: I've had already looked there and the corrext translation is present

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure what you are asking